# Running into an error when trying to pip install python-docx

Tags: python

I just did a fresh install of windows to clean up my computer, moved everything over to my D drive and installed Python through Windows Store (somehow it defaulted to my C drive, so I left it there because Pycharm was getting confused about its location), now I'm trying to pip install the python-docx module for the first time and I'm stuck. I have a recent version of Microsoft C++ Visual Build Tools installed. Excuse me for any irrelevant information I provided, just wishing to be thorough. Here's what's returning in command:

```
.>pip install python-docx
Collecting python-docx
  Using cached python-docx-0.8.11.tar.gz (5.6 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting lxml>=2.3.2
  Using cached lxml-4.6.3.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for python-docx, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for lxml, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: lxml, python-docx
    Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\cahez\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\cahez\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8rz9vrlv\\lxml_69e9fa188fd042d6953641882e4b3a17\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\cahez\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8rz9vrlv\\lxml_69e9fa188fd042d6953641882e4b3a17\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\cahez\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xpg_v_i_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\cahez\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Include\lxml'
         cwd: C:\Users\cahez\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8rz9vrlv\lxml_69e9fa188fd042d6953641882e4b3a17\
    Complete output (76 lines):
    Building lxml version 4.6.3.
    Building without Cython.
    Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
    running install
    C:\Users\cahez\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\cahez\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\cahez\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8rz9vrlv\\lxml_69e9fa188fd042d6953641882e4b3a17\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\cahez\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8rz9vrlv\\lxml_69e9fa188fd042d6953641882e4b3a17\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\cahez\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xpg_v_i_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\cahez\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Include\lxml' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The third to last line about needing MSVC seems worth pursuing, have you tried that yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the dependencies for `python-docx` is `lxml`. The latest stable version of `lxml` is 4.6.3, released on March 21, 2021. On PyPI there is [no lxml wheel for 3.10](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/#files), yet. So it try to compile from source and for that Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required, as stated in the error.

However you can manually install `lxml`, before install `python-docx`. Download and install [unofficial binary from Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)
Alternatively you can use [pipwin](https://pypi.org/project/pipwin/) to install it from Gohlke. Note there may still be problems with dependencies for `lxml`.

Of course, you can also downgrade to python3.9.

EDIT: As of 14 Dec 2021 the latest lxml version 4.7.1 supports python 3.10